# How can I get the Unknown Sources option on my Dell Streak?

Tags: applications, settings

I want to install one application which is not in the Market. I know that if I want to do that I should switch on the "Unknown sources" option, but I don't have "Unknown sources" on my Dell Streak. What should I do to get this option?

Comment: What version of Android are you running?  Specific firmware version would be useful too.  I assume you've looked for Unknown Sources in `Settings -> Applications`?

Comment: What is your carrier?

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your firmware version, you might be able to abuse the ability turn-on engineering mode. Taken from [StreakSmart](http://www.streaksmart.com/2010/08/how-to-sideload-apps-on-stock-att-dell-streak-without-root-adb-or-sideload-wonder-machine.html):

- Dial `*#*#307#*#*` on your Streak. Other than a quick flash on the screen, it will look like nothing has happened.
- Go to your app drawer/program menu and tap a new icon labeled EMList. If the icon is not there, turn off the Streak. It should be there when you turn it on again.
- Scroll to the bottom and tap app_security.
- Tap update unknown resource property to enable it.

This will be the only way without installing a custom rom (Google StreakDroid)

Answer (score -2):

First you need to enable the option to install application through unknown sources, you can achieve this in

```
Settings >> Applications >> Unknown Sources
```

Then you can use [ADB](http://voxigee.wordpress.com/2010/02/28/using-adb-to-install-applications/) to install applications from your PC or use [ASTRO File Manger](http://www.appbrain.com/app/astro-file-manager/com.metago.astro) to install applications in your SD card.